# Tailgate door open warning issue 14 Ford Escape

Tags: ford, locks, warning-light

I have a 2014 Ford Escape that is giving tailgate door open warning  on dashboard display even though the door is latched close. I also noticed that the tailgate door does not lock shut. There is no key on tailgate and using the door lock button on side doors doesn’t have any effect. Are these issues related ( tailgate door alarm/ tailgate don’t lock) and how to fix. The latch itself has been replaced.

Comment: I have a few questions to better understand what is going on. When did the problem start? Was the latch replaced because of this issue? Or did the issue start after the latch was replaced? When you say the tailgate door does not lock shut, do you mean it is free to open while driving?

Comment: Has the recall for the door latches been completed? [Faulty door latches prompt Ford to recall 830K vehicles](http://www.detroitnews.com/story/business/autos/ford/2016/08/04/ford-recall/88062424/?utm_source=twitterfeed&utm_medium=twitter)

Comment: I had some netting that was loose and got caught up in door latch. I closed the door on it and I’ve had issue with latch ever since. ( latch not secure/ door ajar warning)The were some parts in the latch that broke that couldn’t be repaired, so I replaced latch.  Latch stays secure now, but all you have to do now is open tailgate like normal and door opens- it doesn’t lock. The recall was for side latches, not back. The recall you are referring to has been done.

Comment: I have the same exact problem on my 2013 escape. I changed the latch much ($136 from ford), that did not fix the problem. Going back at it today, I think the hook may be bent, trying that first. I can't find any other sensor or switch, but looking into that also.

Comment: I wound up rewiring it so that it made sensor think it was closed all the time.

Answer (score 2):

With the key on, open the liftgate and push the latch in with a screwdriver to engage it. If the warning is still on, remove the latch, unplug the harness and check continuity in the connector on the latch when it’s open and closed. If the resistance doesn’t change, chances are it’s a bad latch.